# Flask autoescaping for files with uncommon extentions

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I found that in flask >= 0.5 there is autoescaping enabled only for the little amount of extensions not including j2. I use j2 extentions for my templates to get coloring and another features from my editor. So how can I enable autoescaping for certain file extentions in Flask in the most simple and convenient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#autoescaping

To enable it globally you can use :

```
from jinja2 import select_autoescape

app.jinja_env.autoescape = select_autoescape(       
    default_for_string=True,         
    default=True       
)
```

Or for specified extensions :

```
app.jinja_env.autoescape = select_autoescape(      
    default_for_string=True,    
    enabled_extensions=('html', 'xml', 'j2')
)
```